# How can I apply according style as attribute for SVG Elements in D3 or JS

Tags: css, d3.js, svg, html2canvas

When I use D3 to manipulate SVG elements, I applied both `attr(such as x, y cx, cy)` and `style(such as stroke, text-anchor, fill)` to SVG Element, for D3 itself only, this works pretty well,

but when I try to use **html2Canvas.js** to take a snapshot, then the style part in SVG elements become buggy, I gave a few tries, it turns out when I put those style as attr, then everything works again, so I wonder how can I move all valid styles into attr(I need to keep the style, cos I sometimes, only setting as style can work)

Or another direct help could be how could I make **html2canvas** recognize both attr and style and just get their final cooperative effect.

Comment: Are you setting the style via a style attribute (for example, `style="stroke: #333; fill: #999;"`) or as individual attributes (`stroke="#333"`, `fill="#999"`, etc.)? Does changing to the other way of doing things help the problem?

Comment: @MaxStarkenburg actually I do not know which setting works, but I just give a try,  I want to set the attr while keeping the style.

Answer (score 0):

Try converting the svg to canvas first. There is a project https://github.com/gabelerner/canvg out there, which may help you. After converting the svg, html2canvas should be able to render the snapshot correctly.

Comment: Thanks, before trying it, I wonder if this canvg can recognize both style(inline or via style sheet) and attr?

Comment: Yes it can, as long as the style is defined in the svg, see http://jsfiddle.net/9ncuf42o/ for styled variant and http://jsfiddle.net/cc1nt89k/ for attributed variant.

Answer (score 0):

If we are only talking about styles that are set via style attributes, not using a stylesheet, then the following is an option that is independant of d3:

```
var svgElements = document.querySelectorAll("svg *");
Array.prototype.forEach.call(svgElements, function(svgElement){
  var styles = svgElement.getAttribute("style").split(";");
  styles.forEach(function(style){
    var styleComponents = style.split(":");
    svgElement.setAttribute(
      styleComponents[0].trim(),
      styleComponents[1].trim()
    );
  });
});
```

You'll have to modify the selector in the first line to match your use case.

Comment: Sorry I guess I did not quite get it, what means **not styles that are applied using CSS selectors**?